# Does spin-0 or spin-2 describe massive or massless particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, quantum-spin, relativity, group-representations

spin-0 is massive or massless?
How does we separate the massive and massless degrees of freedom for spin-2?
What is the  partially massive?

Comment: YOu can have both massive and massless particles at both spins.  There are beleived to be stability problems with massive spin-2 theories, though.

Answer (score 7):

Spin-0 can be either massive *or* massless.  Examples of known massive spin-0 particles are the pion $\pi^+$, kaon $K^+$, and also the recently discovered Higgs boson $H$.  No known spin-0 particles are exactly massless, but the Goldstone boson arising from the spontaneous breakdown of a continuous internal symmetry is a good theoretical example.

Spin-2 can be either massive *or* massless.  Examples of known massive spin-2 particles are the lighter tensor mesons, $f_2$, $a_2$ or the heavier charmonium meson $\chi_{c2}$.  No known spin-2 particle is massless, but the overwhelming consensus is that the graviton, the mediator of gravity, must exist.